# How to selectively remove punctuation between two entry fields in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I want to change the output of `@thesis` entry fields. Currently, I'm using the `biblatex` style `chem-acs`.

Using the entry:

```
@thesis{ABC2019,
author = {LastName, A.},
school = {University of example},
title = {Title of fancy science stuff},
type = {PhD thesis},
year = {2019}
}
```

I get:

> LastName, A. Title of fancy science stuff., PhD thesis, University of example, 2019.

However, I want to follow some journal citation rules, which require to remove the comma delimiter after the title. So what I'm aiming for is:

> LastName, A. Title of fancy science stuff. PhD thesis, University of example, 2019.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm sure you got a warning in the `*.blg` file, right? Please show it us. And please add a short compilable tex code building your bibliography to your question, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: For future questions, please note that it is much easier for people to help you if you can add a full example document to your question that shows not only relevant `.bib` entries, but also how you call your bibliography in your document. In this case the only really crucial piece of information was that you use `chem-acs` and that was mentioned in the body text, but that is not always the case and a full example document makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing.

Comment: @moewe: sorry for my short question post, you are completely right in asking for a proper MWE...Nethertheless, you guessed exactly right with your answer, which completly solved my problems. and indeed, the double punctuation looks weird. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the output you actually want, the output you get at the moment doesn't look quite right.

> Geer, I. de Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music, The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study., Ph.D. Thesis, Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet, 1985.

The double punctuation ".," would be regarded as a mistake by most people. I have reported this at https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem/issues/16.

If you wanted a comma after the title, the fix would be as easy as

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
```

But you want a period, so some more work is needed.

There are several possible ways to deal with this and they all have their advantages and drawbacks.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=chem-acs, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}%
  \printunit{\addperiod\space}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> Geer, I. de Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music, The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study. Ph.D. Thesis, Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet, 1985.